# How can I open pdf in my webview using google Docs? (Suddenly it's not work)

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Not long age, I can open pdf in my webview using below my code.

```
view.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + str);
```

But suddenly it's not work.

I don't know the reason.

How can I open pdf in my webview??

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is repeated, I get the solution

1) Type:

```
 webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?url="+pdfUrl.get(position).url);
```

2) Don't forget to set webview client

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }

        }

    });
```